# Error: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I build new Project in android studio Java language and Run 'app' failed show error.

I installed New program and installed new windows but Run failed show error.

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project D:\File\Android Project\MyApplication

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:dexBuilderDebug
> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.google.common.base.VerifyException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
15 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 13 up-to-date
```

Answer (score 9):

This code will solve problem

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst "META-INF/DEPENDENCIES"
    }
}
```

or

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude "META-INF/DEPENDENCIES"
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error after adding this. Error: The application has specified that a custom LogFactory implementation should be used but class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl' cannot be converted to 'org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory'. Could you please help me how to resolve this?

Comment: any solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

> flutter clean
>
> flutter pub get

This works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My ISP is using custom SSL infrastructure which blocked the Gradle downloads from: https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/arm64_v8a_debug/

Once I connected to the internet with a standard connection the build completed without error.

Answer (score 0):

the main problem in pubspec.yaml file
make sure to edit pubspec.yaml correctly then
 `flutter clean && flutter pub get`